# Horizontal recycler view with width less than match_parent

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Have a horizontal recyclerview. Want the width to be less than match_parent only able to view some pixels of the next item. Is there a way to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all get the screen width.

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
WindowManager windowmanager = (WindowManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
windowmanager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
int deviceWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
```

Then in your adapter fix the width of your view:-

```
item_width = deviceWidth - (deviceWidth/100 * 10);
```

Comment: Worked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just to improve on your answer, you can do 
`int deviceWidth = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;`

Answer (score 0):

```
android:layout_margin = "2dp"
```

should work for this

Comment: i am having a horizontal recyclerview inside a vertical recyclerview. layout_margin is adding margin but width of the item is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Hello vijaydev You can use in your layout weight at particular item and give width 0

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is fix the width of the horizontal item in the layout xml. The picture you uploaded will be occupying varying percentages of the screen on different phones and tablets.
Else you can use a viewpager for the horizontal method. In its adapter you can override the `getpagewidth` method. For it you can return say `0.9f` which will make your element occupy 90% of the screen width.